# spherical buildings for non-split groups

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, buildings

I am looking for references to explicit descriptions of Tits buildings for semisimple (classical) Lie groups via language of incidence geometry. Such descriptions are well-documented in the case of split groups in many sources (e.g. in Garrett's book), but there is hardly anything available in the non-split case. I know how to do so in the pseudo-orthogonal case (groups O(p,q)). In principle, I could run similar arguments for other types (unitary groups over complex numbers, quaternions, etc.), but it is a bit tedious, so I am looking for a reference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Misha, Tits' Lecture Note "Buildings of spherical type and finite BN pairs" 
gives a fairly explicit description of the buildings associated to the 
classical groups (not just the split ones). I also wrote a survey called
"Buildings and classical groups" (arXiv:math/0307117) 
which appeared in print some years ago.
These sources deal with general fields and division rings. Of course,
some details become easier over the reals, the complex numbers and the
quaternions, partly because one does not have to worry about characteristic 2.

The buildings associated to hermitian or symplectic forms (and hence to
orthogonal, unitary or symplectic groups) are also called polar spaces.
Under this name, one can find lots of references.

Here are some more details, based on Section 2.7 in my article arXiv:math/0307117.
Since we are interested in Lie groups, we are dealing with finite dimensional
modules over the reals, the complex numbers or the real quaternions.

We are given a nondegenerate $(\sigma,\epsilon)$-hermitian form $h$ on
a finite dimensional right module $V$ over 
$\mathbb K=\mathbb R,\mathbb C,\mathbb H$. 
This means that $\epsilon=\pm 1$, that $\sigma$ is an involution
(an anti-automorphism whose square is the identity) on $\mathbb K$ and
that $h$ is a $\sigma$-sesqulinear form on $V$, with
$$h(u,va)=h(u,v)a=\epsilon h(va,u)^\sigma\qquad\forall u,v\in V,\ a\in\mathbb K$$
and with $V^\perp=0$. A submodule $W$ is called *totally isotropic* if
$W\subseteq W^\perp$. The building is the simplicial complex consisting 
of all (partial) flags consisting of totally isotropic subspaces.
If we rescale the hermitian form $h$ by multiplying it by a (suitable)
nonzero scalar, the building is obviously not changed.
Up to this rescaling process, there are the following cases.

1) *Symplectic groups* over $\mathbb R,\mathbb C$, where
$\sigma=id_{\mathbb K}$ and $\epsilon=-1$.

2) *Orthogonal groups*  over $\mathbb R,\mathbb C$, where
$\sigma=id_{\mathbb K}$ and $\epsilon=1$.

3) *Unitary groups* over $\mathbb C,\mathbb H$, where
$a^\sigma=\bar a$ is the standard conjugation and $\epsilon=1$.

4) *Unitary groups* over $\mathbb H$, where
$a^\sigma=-i\bar a i $ and $\epsilon=1$.

In case 1) and 2), the building has simplicial dimension $m-1$, were
$\dim(V)=2m$.

In case 3) the building has simplicial dimension
$m-1$, and the form $h$ has signature $(m,m+k)$ for $k\geq 0$.

In case 4), the building has simplicial dimension
$m-1$, and $\dim V=2m$ or $\dim V=2m+1$.

In case 2), if $k=0$, then
the building is not thick. If one want a thick building, one has
to consider instead the "oriflamme geometry" which is explained
for example in Tits' Lecture Note.

Comment: The mentioned article, clickably:  [Kramer - Buildings and classical groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307117).  Thanks for it!